# mongodb aggregate multiple nested fields

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a document structure like,

```
{
  "id" : 123
  "b" [
        {
         "dd"   : 21,
         "mm"   : 05,
         "yyyy" : 2015
         "prod" : "xyz"
         },
        {
         "dd"   : 22,
         "mm"   : 05,
         "yyyy" : 2015
         "prod" : "abc"
         }
       ]
 },
 {
  "id" : 512
  "b" [
        {
         "dd"   : 11,
         "mm"   : 05,
         "yyyy" : 2015
         "prod" : "xdyz"
         },
        {
         "dd"   : 22,
         "mm"   : 05,
         "yyyy" : 2015
         "prod" : "abac"
         }
       ]
 },
.....
```

the jsons in the list indicate date. How do I get count of dates in all documents? I want an aggregate count like

```
2015-05-22  count: 2
2015-05-21  count: 1
2015-05-11  count: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
db.Testing.aggregate([
    {'$unwind': '$b'},
    { $project: 
        { date: 
            { $concat: [
                { 
                    "$substr": [ "$b.dd", 0, 2 ] }, "-", { "$substr": [ "$b.mm", 0, 2 ] }, "-", { "$substr": [ "$b.yyyy", 0, 4 ] }
            ]}
        }
    },
    {'$group': {'_id':'$date','Count':{'$sum': 1}} }
])
```

Result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "11-5-2015",
            "Count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "22-5-2015",
            "Count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "21-5-2015",
            "Count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following aggregation framework will be a close match to what you need:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$b"
    },
    {   
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "dd" : "$b.dd",
                "mm" : "$b.mm",
                "yyyy" : "$b.yyyy"
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
]);
```

With the above sample collection, you will get the following aggregation result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "dd" : 22,
                "mm" : 5,
                "yyyy" : 2015
            },
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "dd" : 11,
                "mm" : 5,
                "yyyy" : 2015
            },
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "dd" : 21,
                "mm" : 5,
                "yyyy" : 2015
            },
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If the array element field values were of string type then you could do some [**`$concat`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) operation on those fields in your **`$project`** pipeline stage to get the desired output